# SpaCy-UDpipe load custom model colab

Tags: model, google-colaboratory, spacy, udpipe

### I'm trying to load a custom spacy-udpipe model into google colab.
I tried

```
!pip install ufal.udpipe

!pip install spacy-udpipe
```

```py
import spacy_udpipe

nlp = udpipe_download_model(language = ("italian-postwita"))
```

---

but I get the following error message : NameError: name 'udpipe_download_model' is not defined.

Anyone can help?
thanks

Comment: You have not imported `udpipe_download_model`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import spacy_udpipe

spacy_udpipe.download("name_of_model_to_download")
```